# Generate Query Hash and Query Plan Hashes for lots of Queries in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am working on optimizing the load on a decently large SQL server 2008 cluster, and I have a sample of the queries being submitted to the server over a short timespan.  This amounts to about 1.7 million queries and I am working on determining how many are one off ad-hoc queries and how many are substantially the same and being submitted often by applications so that the highest usage and highest resource intensive queries are optimized first.

To do this, I wish to use the Query Hash and Query Plan hashes, and add them to my analysis table.   The DMV's in SQL server only keep these values for a few minutes (maybe a bit longer depending on memory usage) so I can't query the DMV's to pull the hashes.  I know that the hashes can be generated one at a time by using the SET SHOWPLAN_XML option, but that isn't exactly friendly as showplan must be turned on, the result returned and parsed, then show plan turned off to save to a table.

I am hoping there is an undocumented function that can generate the 2 hashes and return a value I can store to a table; so far I haven't found one.  Does anyone know of such a function?

Comment: I was unable to find any built in processes to do this besides making a SSIS package to create sqlplans in xml (which have the query plan and query plash), so I solved this by pulling the query hash and query plan hashs from the DMV's and storing them to a table for a new date range.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this workaround?  Thanks in advance!